# How to Control an I-Beam Trolley with a PLC

Tags: ac, wiring, plc

I recently bought an [i-beam trolley](http://www.northerntool.com/shop/tools/product_200660196_200660196), and want to control it via my [PLC](https://controllino.biz/controllino/) instead of the pendant. I cut the pendant cord and found 3 wires. Green/yellow (presumably the ground), blue, and pink. Using the relays, I connected the ground to the blue wire, then the ground to the pink wire, but nothing happened. Even tried connecting the pink and blue wires, but still nothing. The trolley worked with the pendant, and the PLC setup works with other 3-wire motors. What else could it be? Perhaps there's something different required for A/C current?

Answer (score 2):

I would look in the pendant to see how the cable connects to the switches.

If you've discarded the pendant, then look in the control unit, to see how the cable connects to it.  You may have to draw a wiring diagram of the control unit to figure out the function of the wires.

If the pendant only has two switches, figuring this out should be trivial.  If more switches, there may be electronics and serial data communication which will be more difficult to reverse-engineer.